# Left and right alignment on the same row (RTF FILE)

Tags: c++, rtf

I need to write some text - a little on the left and a little on the right , but it's must be on the same line.

I need a code in rtf, because it will auto-generate by app in c++.

What RTF code can set text on the same line left and flushed right?

Comment: Okay. So what's the question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a tab ruler with a right aligned tab at the far right and insert a tab between the two texts.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil;}}
\pard\tqr\tx8236\f0 test\tab test\par
}
```